# Magento EE Cannot upgrade from 2.2.7 to 2.3.3 via composer

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.3

I'm trying to update Magento EE 2.2.7 to version 2.3.3 using the command line:

I have tried using bellow command but getting errors

- Command :

> composer update

Output:

```
Problem 1
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc30 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc23 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc22 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc21 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc2 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc1 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 requires magento/framework 100.1.*||101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9, 101.0.10].
    - snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 requires magento/framework 100.1.*||101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9, 101.0.10].
    - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 2.7.7].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 2.7.7].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1].
    - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.3].
    - Installation request for snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 -> satisfiable by snowdog/theme-blank-sass[1.100.4].
```

if anyone has an idea help me..!